# openssl error : implicit declaration of MD5Init

Tags: c, authentication, encryption, openssl, hmac

First of all I am showing the code for my c file ..

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "sendip_module.h"
#include "ipv6ext.h"
#include "../ipv6.h"
#include "../ipv4.h"
#include "ah.h"
#include "esp.h"
#include "crypto_module.h"

#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

/*
code for hmac_md5 here....

void
hmac_md5(text, text_len, key, key_len, digest)
unsigned char*  text;                /* pointer to data stream */
int text_len;            /* length of data stream */
unsigned char* key;                 /* pointer to authentication key */
int key_len;             /* length of authentication key */
caddr_t digest;              /* caller digest to be filled in */

{
    MD5_CTX context;
    unsigned char k_ipad[65];    /* inner padding -
                                  * key XORd with ipad
                                  */
    unsigned char k_opad[65];    /* outer padding -
                                  * key XORd with opad
                                  */
    unsigned char tk[16];
    int i;
    /* if key is longer than 64 bytes reset it to key=MD5(key) */
    if (key_len > 64) {

            MD5_CTX      tctx;

            MD5Init(&tctx);
            MD5Update(&tctx, key, key_len);
            MD5Final(tk, &tctx);

            key = tk;
            key_len = 16;
    }

    /*
     * the HMAC_MD5 transform looks like:
     *
     * MD5(K XOR opad, MD5(K XOR ipad, text))
     *
     * where K is an n byte key
     * ipad is the byte 0x36 repeated 64 times
     * opad is the byte 0x5c repeated 64 times
     * and text is the data being protected
     */

    /* start out by storing key in pads */
    bzero( k_ipad, sizeof k_ipad);
    bzero( k_opad, sizeof k_opad);
    bcopy( key, k_ipad, key_len);
    bcopy( key, k_opad, key_len);

    /* XOR key with ipad and opad values */
    for (i=0; i<64; i++) {
            k_ipad[i] ^= 0x36;
            k_opad[i] ^= 0x5c;
    }
    /*
     * perform inner MD5
     */
    MD5Init(&context);                   /* init context for 1st
                                          * pass */
    MD5Update(&context, k_ipad, 64);      /* start with inner pad */
    MD5Update(&context, text, text_len); /* then text of datagram */
    MD5Final(digest, &context);          /* finish up 1st pass */
    /*
     * perform outer MD5
     */
    MD5Init(&context);                   /* init context for 2nd
                                          * pass */
    MD5Update(&context, k_opad, 64);     /* start with outer pad */
    MD5Update(&context, digest, 16);     /* then results of 1st
                                          * hash */
    MD5Final(digest, &context);          /* finish up 2nd pass */
```

}

*/

```
/*
rest of the program logic...
*/
```

I have already included ...<.path where openssl is installed.....>../openssl/include to C_INCLUDE_PATH and exported it.

and now when i try to compile it getting error :

```
 $ make

gcc -o xorauth.so -I.. -fPIC -fsigned-char -pipe -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings
wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Werror -g -Wcast-align -  
DSENDIP_LIBS=\"/usr/local/lib/sendip\" -shared xorauth.c ../libsendipaux.a  
../libsendipaux.a

cc1: warnings being treated as errors

xorauth.c:34:1: error: function declaration isn’t a prototype
xorauth.c: In function ‘hmac_md5’:
xorauth.c:56:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘MD5Init’
xorauth.c:56:17: error: nested extern declaration of ‘MD5Init’
xorauth.c:57:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘MD5Update’
xorauth.c:57:17: error: nested extern declaration of ‘MD5Update’ 
xorauth.c:58:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘MD5Final’
xorauth.c:58:17: error: nested extern declaration of ‘MD5Final’
make: *** [xorauth.so] Error 1
```

if required I will edit the other implementation details I have skiped them just to make the post small because I think there is something which i need to do regarding include path and header files and i am unaware of it.

What is going wrong please help me ???

Comment: It's likely `<other header files>` are doing something nasty (like forgetting a semicolon or a bracket).

Comment: @cnicutar I checked but they are fine and code is working fine after removing the hmac_md5 function and the two header files

Comment: At least show us the lines in xorauth.c that trigger the error messages (lines 34 and 56).  The message on line 34 doesn't look fatal, by using a prototype rather than an old-style function declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `MD5Init` function in OpenSSL.  (There is in the BSD implementation.)

`man MD5_Init` (note the underscore), or see [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html).

**EDIT**:

Now that you've shown us the offending code, I can also help with the "not a prototype" message.

You have (edited a bit):

```
void hmac_md5(text, text_len, key, key_len, digest)
unsigned char*  text;                
int text_len;            
unsigned char* key;                 
int key_len;             
caddr_t digest;              
{
    /* ... */
}
```

That's an old-style, or "K&R", function definition.  It's still valid, but only for backward compatibility, and it means that the compiler won't be able to warn you about calls with the wrong number or type(s) of arguments.  The modern (since 1989) version is:

```
void hmac_md5(unsigned char *text, 
              int text_len, 
              unsigned char *key, 
              int key_len, 
              caddr_t digest)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

When converting old-style function declarations and definitions to use prototypes, you sometimes have to be careful about parameters with narrow types (float, and integer types narrower than int or unsigned int) due to the promotion rules.  That doesn't apply in this particular case.

Note that you *can* leave the definition as it is if you like.  Since you got the code from an internet draft, that might even be a good idea (if it ain't broke, don't fix it) -- but as I said you'll get no help from the compiler if you call it with the wrong number or type(s) of arguments.

Comment: oh........ya thanks it was the mistake actually it was part of an internet draft but now there is one more error for `hmac_md5` , its saying `function declaration is not a prototype` .Is there a replacment for it also ???

Comment: ya thats perfectly compiled now and after `sudo make install` the xorauth.so is also peftectly made . but when i run my project using this xorauth.so then its showing error again..                             `Couldn't open module xorauth, tried:
 xorauth: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 ./xorauth.so: undefined symbol: MD5_Init
 /usr/local/lib/sendip/xorauth.so: undefined symbol: MD5_Init
 /usr/local/lib/sendip/xorauth: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I think you have already answer my question for this post so if you have answer to my this new problem i can close this thread by accepting answer so that this thread is closed and repost the new error as a new question.

Comment: The `cannot open shared object file` messages are linker errors, not compiler errors.  If you're using gcc, try adding `-lssl` or something similar to the command line.

Comment: @Kevin Thompson where can i add the switch i am using `make` so tried using it with `make` and also tried with `make install` but the error is same.also when openssl header files and related code is commented its working.

Comment: You wrote that there is a `MD5Init` in the BSD implementation of openssl. Could you point me towards the code? I have been unsuccessful searching for it. Even in the 2000 version of freeBSD, the function was called `MD5_Init`: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/2e467dc342d6641955ef59a1a671ff929444d45b/crypto/openssl/crypto/md5/md5.h

Comment: @ARF: I don't remember (I posted the answer more than 3 years ago).